# rsync to Android device not detecting existing files

Tags: android, rsync

I am trying to rsync a directory from my Linux Mint 20.3 machine to my Pixel 6 using the following command:

```
rsync -hvr --progress --omit-dir-times --no-perms --inplace /linux_dir/ /run/user/*/gvfs/*/Internal\ shared\ storage/android_dir/
```

The initial file copy proceeds as I expect; I can see and open the files on my phone. However, if I run the command again, it proceeds to re-copy every file over again, seemingly without taking into account the files that already exist on the phone. Any idea why that may be?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the use of "--omit-dir-times".

Basic uncomplicated rsync **needs size and time for comparison**.

If unable to match both (you aren't providing the time), rsync deems all directories to be copied, and by implication, the contents of those directories.